# Execution Policy of Java Executor

Tags: java

I'm using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`and the javadoc says that : 
`tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially`. So I supposed that my `List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>()` will be ordered but it's not the case.

First element of the list is the result of the 3rd thread ...

```
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
        futures.add(pool.submit(new ThreadTest()));
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String test= futures.get(0).get(); <-- The result of the 3rd thread
    String test1 = futures.get(1).get(); <-- The result of the 5th thread 
    .....
```

I didn't get the logic.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Sequentially only mean one-at-a-time.  The wording does not guarantee anything about the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Executor will only process one task in parallel - you are submitting all your tasks at once - which means they are "made available" to the execution queue.

The Executor will be able to pick any of the tasks in the queue and distribute it to exactly one runner thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I though the same thing. Do you have any idea how to apply FIFO policy ?

Comment: call Future.get() after every submit before submitting the next token